# Incorporating additional conditions on `FindInstance` or `Solve` for a cubic map

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, conditional

I have the cubic map:

`f[a_, x_] := (a - 1) x - a x^3`

To determine the values of a for which this cubic map is bounded to the closed interval -1 and +1, I tried:

`Solve[f[a, x] == x && -1 <= x <= 1 && -1 <= a <= 1, x]`

But mathematica returns the output as

`{{x->ConditionalExpression[0,-1<a<1]}}`

which isn't at all sensible.
If I try:

`roots = Flatten[Solve[f[x, a] == x, x]]`
I get three roots, two of which contains the bifurcation variable "a". It is this variable "a" that I must determine so that the map remains in the closed interval -1 and +1.

I haven't any familiarity with to conditional in programming so help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you need. The output of `Solve` is correct. Can you clarify of what exactly the output should be.

Comment: @AnjanKumar
What you're saying is that `Solve` is performing correctly. But that's not my question.
My question is whether Mathematica is giving me something that I want mathematically.  
The roots to the cubic map (without any contraints) are 
`roots = Flatten[Solve[f[x, a] == x, x]]`.
Taking the solution `roots[[2]]` and substituting in a=100, the map remains in the domain [-1,1]. 
Clearly, a=100 is a counterexample to the output.
Would it be clearer if I said "for what values of "a" such that the map f remains in the closed interval"?

Comment: I understand now. Try this: `Reduce[-1 <= -(Sqrt[-2 + a]/Sqrt[a]) <= 1 && -1 <= Sqrt[-2 + a]/Sqrt[a] <= 1, a]`. This gives `a>=2`, which looks like there won't be any solution b/w `[-1,1]`.

Comment: Thank you. I may now use the above to evaluate for the remaining solution.
However, I believe a more elegant-and powerful-method is to instruct mathematica to determine the values of "a" for which the map is bounded to the closed interval. Can this be done?

Comment: Actually, the result you get from `Solve[]` says the same. There is a solution only when `x` is `0` and `a` is `[-1, 1]` (which I believe is not what you are after). You can try using `Reduce` too like this: `Reduce[f[a, x] == x && -1 <= x <= 1 && -1 <= a <= 1, x]`.

Comment: @AnjanKumar Thank you. I had wanted to ensure that my mathematical codes are giving me a mathematically correct answer.

Comment: @AnjanKumar Why don't you turn your comments into an answer that can be upvoted and accepted?

Comment: @halirutan Sure. I have turned them into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The result you obtain from [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) is correct. It says that there is a solution only when `x` is `0` and `a` is `[-1, 1]`.

You can also verify that two of the three roots (other than `x->0`) don't satisfy the limits of `x` and `a`.

```
Reduce[-1 <= -(Sqrt[-2 + a]/Sqrt[a]) <= 1 && -1 <= Sqrt[-2 + a]/Sqrt[a] <= 1, a]
```

> a >= 2 (*which is out of range*)